# "Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open" & can't figure out how to center horizontally?

Tags: css, html

I'm really new at this so I'm sure this is a simple mistake- could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to center my content, and my code is invalid. I'm thinking it's a nesting error, but I'm not sure.

(There's also an error stating that my "align" attribute is obsolete, which my teacher is telling me to ignore for the time being)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javajam.css">
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
<header>
  <h1><img src="javalogo.gif" alt="JavaJam Coffee House" width="700" height="100"></h1>
</header>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="music.html">Music</a>&nbsp;
      <a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a>&nbsp;
    </nav>

    <main>
      <img src="windingroad.jpg" alt="Winding Road" height="154" width="333" align="right">
      <ul>
        <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
        <li>Bagels. Muffins and Organic Snacks</li>
        <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
        <li>Open Mic Night</li>
      </ul>
    </main>

    <div>
      12312 Main Street
      <br>Mountain Home, CA 93923
      <br>1-888-555-5555
    </div>&nbsp;



    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2014 JavaJam Coffee House
      <br>ari.levy@gmail.com
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: center what part of the content? theres several elements on it.

Comment: Can you please post your css file?  I don't see the align attribute that you are referring to except for the image tag.  Where is the align attribute that you are having trouble with?

Comment: The align attribute that I was talking about actually was the one in the image tag! I think it's supposed to be a substitute for the float property since our class hasn't covered that yet.

Comment: @freestock.tk The instructions say to center the entire web page, and put the wrapper right after the body tag. So...all of it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<header>` tag is on a wrong place and you miss the `<head>` tag

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javajam.css">
  <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>

</head>

<body>

.....

<!-- Place your <header> tag between the <body> tag -->

.....


</body>
</html>`
```

[More Info](http://www.developer.com/lang/understanding-the-proper-way-to-lay-out-a-page-with-html5.html)